# Integral of constant divided by polynomial and another constant

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

$$\int_{-\infty}^{-1}\frac{4}{\sqrt{x^6+2}}\,dx$$

What are the steps to integrate?

Comment: I edited your post. Is this what you meant?

Comment: the x^6+2 is all in the square root symbol

Comment: Is this not what I have done?

Comment: @Annie This is more than just a regular improper convergent integral...May I ask where this problem comes from (course?) Just curious...

Comment: A.P. Calculus B.C.

Comment: @Annie Are you familiar with elliptic integrals?

Comment: No. can a direct comparison, or limit comparison test work to solve the problem?

Comment: @Annie No, those are just tests of convergence that determine whether the integral has a value or not. They don't tell you what the value is though.

Answer (score 1):

**IF** your upper limit would have been $0$ instead of $-1$, then we could easily have expressed this definite integral in terms of a $($regular$)$ [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function). As it stands, we can only do so by using an [incomplete beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function) instead. To do that, first rewrite the whole integral using the [parity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions) of its integrand, then factor $2$ outside of the radical sign. Then let $x^6=2~t^6$, and $u=\dfrac1{\sqrt{t^6+1}}$. The expression of the afore-mentioned special function will soon emerge.

Answer (score 0):

$\int_{-\infty}^{-1}\dfrac{4}{\sqrt{x^6+2}}dx$

$=\int_\infty^1\dfrac{4}{\sqrt{(-x)^6+2}}d(-x)$

$=\int_1^\infty\dfrac{4}{\sqrt{x^6+2}}dx$

$=\int_1^\sqrt[6]2\dfrac{4}{\sqrt{x^6+2}}dx+\int_\sqrt[6]2^\infty\dfrac{4}{\sqrt{x^6+2}}dx$

$=\int_1^\sqrt[6]2\dfrac{2\sqrt2}{\sqrt{1+\dfrac{x^6}{2}}}dx+\int_\sqrt[6]2^\infty\dfrac{4}{x^3\sqrt{1+\dfrac{2}{x^6}}}dx$

$=\int_1^\sqrt[6]22\sqrt2\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!x^{6n}}{4^n(n!)^22^n}dx+\int_\sqrt[6]2^\infty\dfrac{4}{x^3}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!2^n}{4^n(n!)^2x^{6n}}dx$

$=\int_1^\sqrt[6]2\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!x^{6n}}{2^{3n-\frac{3}{2}}(n!)^2}dx+\int_\sqrt[6]2^\infty\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!x^{-6n-3}}{2^{n-2}(n!)^2}dx$

$=\left[\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!x^{6n+1}}{2^{3n-\frac{3}{2}}(n!)^2(6n+1)}\right]_1^\sqrt[6]2+\left[\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!x^{-6n-2}}{2^{n-2}(n!)^2(-6n-2)}\right]_\sqrt[6]2^\infty$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!2^{n+\frac{1}{6}}}{2^{3n-\frac{3}{2}}(n!)^2(6n+1)}-\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!}{2^{3n-\frac{3}{2}}(n!)^2(6n+1)}+\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!2^{-n-\frac{1}{3}}}{2^{n-1}(n!)^2(3n+1)}$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!}{2^{2n-\frac{5}{3}}(n!)^2(6n+1)}-\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!}{2^{3n-\frac{3}{2}}(n!)^2(6n+1)}+\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!}{2^{2n-\frac{2}{3}}(n!)^2(3n+1)}$